# GParted cannot create new partitions

Tags: fedora, gparted, bugs

I just install Fedora 24 few days ago and when I tried to create a new partitions to be my stuffs place GParted show an error. I've about 800 GB of unused space and I really need it,I'm familiar with Debian Based Disto and this is the first time I use RedHat based system
[image: GParted in Fedora cannot create new partitions]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should also show the partition configuration you told GParted to create so that someone could spot if you made a mistake in there? (I don't know if GParted allows configuring partitions in a wrong way but that's what I'd first suspect).

Comment: Done,I include more details about my partitions table

Comment: What if you first delete `sda9`, then recreate it after adding the new partitions? Be aware that the numbers of subsequent partitions will change when you insert a new one between - best practice would be to not leave gaps, but fill the unallocated space from start to end (left to right in *GParted*). If *GParted* doesn't work, try good old `fdisk` (as root, of course).